# Как исправить поведение sendAjaxPostRequest()?

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Всем привет. Пишу функциональный тест под YII2, для "нажатия" на кнопку использую sendAjaxPostRequest():

```
$I->sendAjaxPostRequest('/some/action', ['id' => $id]);
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->seeElement('body');
```

В итоге тест фейлится:

```
Test  tests\functional\myСest.php:tryToTest
Step  See element "body"
Fail  Element located either by name, CSS or XPath element with 'body' was not found.
```

После sendAjaxPostRequest() все страницы начинают считываться в виде json-строки. Примерный вывод myСest.tryToTest.fail.html:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang=\"ru-RU\">\r\n    <head>\r\n        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\r\n... "
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вернуть поведение теста к нормальному виду? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нашел вариант восстанавливать формат ответа сервера после каждого ajax-запроса. Решение не красивое, но есть ли другое?
```\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_HTML;```

Comment: А если вместо `$I->seeElement('body');` поискать в json?

Comment: @fedornabilkin, оказалось, у нас на проекте предыдущий программист во всех action'ах прописал `\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON`. Сейчас думаем, что с этим делать.

Comment: Шикарное решение :)) Наверно поручить ему исправить ситуацию.